# Given a general region evaluate the double integral over that region.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Consider the integral
$$
J = \iint_T \log(1+x^2)\,dx \,dy,
$$
where $T$ is the region that is bounded $y=0$, $x=y$ and $x=2$.

**My attempt:**

$$\int^{x=2}_{x=0} \, \int^{y=x}_{y=0} \log(1+x^2) \,dy\,dx $$

$$\int^2_0 \log(1+ x^2)  \left[\int^x_0 1 \, dy\right]\,dx $$

$$ \tag{1} \int^2_0 x \log(1+x^2) \,dx$$

Base substitution:

$t = 1+x^2$, $\frac{dt}{2}= x\ dx$, UB $= 5$, LB $= 1$,
$$
\tag{2}\frac{1}{2} \int^{t=5}_{t=1} \log(t)\,dt.
$$

Integration by parts :

$ u = \log(t)$, $ du = \frac{1}{t} dt$, $ dv = 1~dt $, $ v = t $,

$$ = u\,v -\int v \, du$$

$$ = \left[ t \, \log(t) \right]^5_1  - \int^5_1 1 ~dt$$

$$\frac{1}{2} \int^{t=5}_{t=1} \log(t)\,dt = \frac{1}{2} \left[ \left[ t \, \log(t) \right]^5_1- [~t~]^5_1 \right] $$

$$ = \frac{1}{2} \left[ 5 \log(5) -4 \right]$$

Final answer :

$$\boxed{ J = \frac{5}{2} \log(5) -2 }$$

could you guys please verify the answer and also I had query

Query/doubt :

The reason I can’t say $ y = 2 $ because, y here could be any value from $0$ to $2$. So it’s more like a variable. So taking $f(x) = 0 $ and $g(x) = x $ as two different function we see $g(x) > f(x)$ between $ 0 \le x \le 2$ .  Making UB = $g(x)$ and LB = $f(x)$ And also $\log(1+ x^2) $ has a $x$ variable inside so it makes sense to take limit of $y$ in terms of $x$. Is this approach correct?

Comment: You may want to use `\iint_T (...)\,dT` which renders as $$\iint_T (...)\,dT$$ for the first integral instead of `\int\,\int_T (...)\,dx\,dy` which looks like $$\int\,\int_T (...)\,dx\,dy$$

Comment: @CiaPan Hey thanks for the response, noted.

Comment: @Aaron Hendrickson thanks for the edit

Comment: @vitamin d thanks for the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

You have used a vertical integration.
With a horizontal integration, we get

$$J=\int_0^2dy(\int_y^2\ln(1+x^2)dx)$$

by parts yields to

$$\int \ln(1+x^2)dx=$$
$$\Bigl[x\ln(1+x^2)\Bigr]-2\int \frac{x^2dx}{1+x^2}$$

$$=x\ln(1+x^2)-2(x-\arctan(x))$$
So

$$J=2(2\ln(5)-2(2-\arctan(2))-$$
$$\int_0^2(y\ln(1+y^2)-2y+2\arctan(y))dy$$

Comment: Hey, thanks for an alternative solution, makes sense.